# Reversed print / logging output from piped commands in R

Tags: r, debugging, logging, pipe

Can anyone explain the reversed order of the printed output from this R script:

```
test_pipe = function(dta, txt) {
  print(txt)
  return(paste(dta,txt))
}

strg = '0'
strg = strg %>%
  test_pipe(1) %>%
  test_pipe(2) %>%
  test_pipe(3)
print(strg)
```

Returns

```
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] "0 1 2 3"
```

Why is 3 printed before 1, while the string output carries the numbers sequentially?

If I replace both print() statements with flog.info(), all output shares exactly the same timestamp:

```
INFO [2023-03-02 08:47:17] 3
INFO [2023-03-02 08:47:17] 2
INFO [2023-03-02 08:47:17] 1
INFO [2023-03-02 08:47:17] 0 1 2 3
```

This example is an analogy of the real world problem of trying to debug a long piped sequence, using print() statements to identify the function at fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to lazy evaluation.  magrittr has the eager pipe which will avoid this (or if you control `test_pipe` insert `force(dta)` as the first line of the body).

```
library(magrittr)

strg = '0'
strg = strg %!>%
  test_pipe(1) %!>%
  test_pipe(2) %!>%
  test_pipe(3)
print(strg)
## [1] 1
## [1] 2
## [1] 3
```